# Rails: geokit "incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, google-geocoder, geokit

I just want to use `geokit` gem with russian characters like following (test it from rails console):

```
Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode 'минск'
```

But get the next error:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
        from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/geokit-1.6.5/lib/geokit/geocoders.rb:464:in `do_geocode'
        from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/geokit-1.6.5/lib/geokit/geocoders.rb:129:in `geocode'
        from (irb):16
        from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Next possible solutions don't help:

```
Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode 'минск'.force_encoding('UTF-8')
Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(CGI.escape('Минск'))

#in config/environment.rb
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8 
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

What can help to solve this problem?
I have the same issue with `google-places` gem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the logger.

https://github.com/imajes/geokit-gem/blob/master/lib/geokit/services/google3.rb#L49

At this line it joins the UTF-8 `address` string and ASCII `json` response. The fix would be to add the following code right before this line:

```
json.force_encoding('utf-8') if json.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
```

You can do that and send the pull request. Just did the same for Nominatim geocoder.